# How to delete the list when linked list nodes are constructed with "new"?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

Question:

You are given two linked lists representing two non-negative numbers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.
Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4) Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8

Solution:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */

ListNode *addTwoNumbers(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) { 
    ListNode dummy(-1); 
    int carry = 0;
    ListNode *prev = &dummy;
    for (ListNode *pa = l1, *pb = l2;
        pa != nullptr || pb != nullptr;
        pa = pa == nullptr ? nullptr : pa->next,
        pb = pb == nullptr ? nullptr : pb->next,
        prev = prev->next) {
        const int ai = pa == nullptr ? 0 : pa->val;
        const int bi = pb == nullptr ? 0 : pb->val;
        const int value = (ai + bi + carry) % 10;
        carry = (ai + bi + carry) / 10;
            prev->next = new ListNode(value); 
        if (carry > 0)
            prev->next = new ListNode(carry);
        return dummy.next;
  }
```

The solution is straightforward but I was wondering since all the nodes are constructed with "new", what will happen after the main function uses this function and terminates the program. The memory allocated by "new" will still be there right? Is this memory leak? Anyway to avoid this?

Comment: The solution would be a **lot** easier if you'd solve this question using `std::list<int>`. C++ is often perfectly capable of doing memory management for you; only in rare cases would you need to so manually. This is not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [delete](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) to deallocate memory allocated with new.

So basically after you're done with your linked lists, you can iterate over it and delete all the nodes by keeping the pointer to next as a temporary variable.

```
while(list){
    temp = list->next;
    delete list;
    list = temp;
}
```

And yes, if you don't delete allocated memory for *any* program after you're done using the data stored in the memory then technically its memory leak. The memory will be cleared once your program exits though.

Comment: Thx! This is what I thought actually but is there any other way to maybe avoid doing this while loop?

Comment: I am now aware of any way that would avoid while loop but if you can always make  deleteList() function using this. In any case, any deallocation with be O(n) in operation time because you have to visit all nodes to delete them. If there was a delete which deleted all together, then it would be against the very idea of linked list (it would be more like an array because arrays have all memory together and hence can be deleted as a group if you know the size). Ummm.. does that make sense? :)

Comment: It's not a leak after the program exits.  Most resources that a program can allocate (memory, files, etc.) will be automatically cleaned up when the program exits.  Resources that aren't automatically cleaned up are rare, special, and buggy.